# ASP.NET Core 6.0 - AWS Cognito - Identity - OpenId

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, openid, asp.net-core-identity

Just want to post my solution in case it helps anyone else.  I really wanted to get my login pages using the hosted UI from AWS Cognito, and I had a lot of issues trying to find a solution, so I just wanted to post what I was able to get working, and if anyone has any additional feedback please let me know.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.ResponseType = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ResponseType"];
    options.MetadataAddress = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:MetadataAddress"];
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientSecret"];
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:CognitoLogout"];
            context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("client_id", builder.Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"]);
            context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("logout_uri", context.HttpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.HttpContext.Request.Host + "/SignOutSuccessful");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.SaveTokens = Convert.ToBoolean(builder.Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:SaveToken"]);
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
//app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```